# How can I reconcile conflicting pull requests proactively?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution

There are two pull requests on a repository, #1 and #2. I submitted #2, but suspect that #1 will be merged first, and it will introduce a merge conflict that will cause my pull request to be rejected.

Is there a way to resolve the merge conflict beforehand, so that if #1 is merged first, git will know how to merge #2 anyway? It's also important that it still works if #1 is rejected. The repository maintainers are not willing to do any extra work to reconcile even trivial conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Make #1 and #2 independent and as soon as one of the two is merged, rebase the other on top, resolving the conflicts and making a force-push to update the PR.

Comment: I'm aware of that- I was wondering if I could proactively do this. The maintainers of the repository only merge PR's once a week, so if I have to rebase afterwards it slows down the cycle a whole week.

Comment: Make 3 PRs, one 2 based on 1 and one 2 not based on 1